# Intellij IDEA skipping closing bracket on test coverage

Tags: unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea, grails, code-coverage

I'm working on a Grails project. When I run unit tests with test coverage, it skips the enclosing brackets from code coverage. It's impossible to get 100% coverage. It happens for all methods.

I tried varying the coverage runner by using JaCoCo and Emma, but no success.

How can I fix this? Why do those brackets get added to total coverage anyway? It's super annoying.

**EDIT**: Actually it skips closing brackets right after `return` (or `break`) statements.

[image]

Comment: I think its an old problem, maybe it could help u: 

https://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205835509-Closing-braces-sometimes-not-being-included-in-code-coverage

Comment: FtR: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166850
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134860